# Why is my gmail email alias suddenly gone?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I have been using an alias on my gmail business account for years. Today I tried to send an email from it and got back an error message:

> You no longer have access to *****. To send this email, choose a
> different ‘from’ address and try again

If I try to send an email, this alias is listed in available *from* options. If I go into my account settings, it is still listed as an alias.

To clarify this is not an external email, it's an alias e.g. my main account is john.smith@widgets.com, the alias is john@widgets.com

What's going on? I use this alias almost as much as the main email address itself.

Comment: Are you the admin of your Google Workspace domain?

Comment: @Rubén yes I am - and the only user.

Answer (score 0):

The typical fix that resolves this hiccup is to remove and re-add the address under "Send mail as".